# How to push an update to a NuGet feed for .NET Framework and .NET Core libraries

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have my own NuGet feed in Azure Artefacts. Currently, there are two packages in the feed:

- INTLConfiguration.Client [Version 1.0.0]
- INTLConfiguration.NetFramework.Client [Version 1.0.0]

The top one is a .NET Core library and the bottom one is a .NET Framework library.

I need to push an update to the NuGet feed for both versions to be 1.0.1 - but I'm having some trouble doing this. I packed 'INTLConfiguration.Client' and renamed the .nukpg from `INTLConfiguration.Client.1.0.0.nupkg` to `INTLConfiguration.Client.1.0.1.nupkg` and tried to push the nuget to my source feed but it errored with a conflict message saying `v1.0.0` already exists.

How do I go about updating both of these nuget packages into my source feed?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I packed 'INTLConfiguration.Client' and renamed the .nukpg from
>   INTLConfiguration.Client.1.0.0.nupkg to
>   INTLConfiguration.Client.1.0.1.nupkg

It seems that your update is just to `rename the output xxx.nupkg`. It's **not the valid way** to create **updated .nupkg**. A `xx.nupkg` is something like a `.zip`. Renaming it from `Name.nupkg` to `Name.zip` and then you can unzip it and see its content. Open the ProjectName.nuspec and you can find the version defined in it is still `1.0.0`.

**My guess:**

Maybe the way you use to pack is something like creating a .net core project and right-click the pack button which outputs a ProjectName.1.0.0.nupkg.

**1#** If so, the easiest way to resolve it is right-click Project name in Solution Explorer=>Properties and change the Package version there:

[image]

Change the version to 1.0.1 and pack it again.

**2#** Also we can use .nuspec file defined by us for this option.

1. Add a text file to the project and rename it to `xxx.nuspec`. Change its `build action` in `property window` to `content`.
2. Right-click the project=>unload the project=>edit the `xxx.csproj` file.

Add a script like below into it:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NuspecFile>NuspecName.nuspec</NuspecFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then `reload the project`, every time when we use Pack option it will call `NuspecName.nuspec` file.

> To create a nuget package by `command-line`, I suggest you use [dotnet.exe or nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#cli-tools).

For your .net core project, you can use `dotnet pack command`.Some details about it see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x#examples).

**3#** To create a `.net core` package with `version 1.0.2` without using a .nuspec file:

1. Open cmd.exe, and type command: `cd C:\PathToProjectFolder` to navigate to ProjectDir(where exists xx.csproj)
2. Then type command like `dotnet pack -p:PackageVersion=1.0.1` to create a really version-1.0.1 nuget package. (If you only have one .csproj in the dir)

Or you need to specify the .csproj like: `dotnet pack ~/projects/app1/project.csproj -p:PackageVersion=1.0.1`

**4#** To create a .net core package with version 1.0.2 using a [.nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#general-form-and-schema) file:

1. Create a .nuspec file and modify its content to meet your needs(Version, AuthorName...).
2. Open cmd.exe and use a command like:`dotnet pack ~/projects/app1/project.csproj /p:NuspecFile=~/projects/app1/project.nuspec /p:NuspecBasePath=~/projects/app1/nuget`

If you use the Pack option(Right-click project=>Pack button) in VS, check 1# or 2#.

If you use command-line, you can check 3# or 4#. Hope it helps:)

**Update:**

> How do I go about updating both of these nuget packages into my source
>   feed?

You can check [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework) to create a package which targets .net framework.And update the version in .nuspec before you pack it. Also, if you want to get an updated nuget package, I suggest you update the assembly version and file version for the dll itself also.